# Prove or disprove: there exists an action of $S_3$ on $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ that is transitive.

Tags: group-theory

With transitive I mean that for every $x, y \in X$, $\exists \sigma \in S_3$, $\sigma(x) = y$.

My attempt: for any action, $(\sigma \tau)(i) = \sigma(\tau(i)) \ (*)$, so $e(i) = i$, and $|S_3| = 6$. Then there must be a $\sigma_2, \sigma_3, \sigma_4, \sigma_5$ such that $\sigma_i(1) = i$. I think the statement is true, because there are enough $\sigma's$ in $S_3$ to realise this, but I have trouble of thinking of one that satisfies *. Is there an easy way to see this?

Comment: It is false because $|S_3|$ is not divisible by $5$.

Comment: What would be the size of each stabiliser?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown would the proof be something like this? $|G(x)| = |G|/|G_x|$ (orbit-stabilizer theorem), so $|G_x| = |G||G(x)|$ where $G(x)$ is the orbit of x, so $|G(x)| = 5$, and $|G| = 6$, so $|G_x| = 30$, so there are 30 distinct elements in $S_3$ that fix $x$, but $|S_3| < 30$, so this is a contradiction and such an action does not exist.

Comment: @DerekHolt, or more concise: by the orbit stabiliser theorem $|G_x| = |G|/|G(x)| = 6/5$ which is not an integer, contradiction.

Comment: @PeldePinda What I wrote is more concise, what you wrote is more precise - but it's correct!